# JAVA - Validation in JTable

Tags: java, validation, swing, jtable

I am trying to validate a cell in the `JTable` as soon as the data is entered. 
I want to make sure that say the correct code is entered in the code column. 
Could anyone let me know how to do this please?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you're trying to validate?

Answer (score 4):

You should implement a `TableCellEditor` and perform your validation within the `stopCellEditing()` method.  If validation fails this method should return `false`.  From the Javadoc:

"Tells the editor to stop editing and accept any partially edited value as the value of the editor. The editor returns false if editing was not stopped; **this is useful for editors that validate and can not accept invalid entries**."

Take a look at the GenericEditor class defined within `JTable` for an example of this.

One other thing worth looking at: You could always construct a `DefaultCellEditor` with a `JFormattedTextField` as a parameter and add an `InputVerifier` to the text field to prevent entry of invalid data from being committed.